# Duplicating jquery script and showing different results

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using the [following script](http://jsfiddle.net/kYvzd/118/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=kYvzd)

i wish to Duplicate the wheel so it will show two, each will show different results.

i have duplicated the html, css and some of the jquery into [here](http://zeevm.co.il/rollet/)
changed the classes of the css and html, it works exept one part:

the problem is that the second wheel don't show resaults.
i have tried to:
a) duplicate the entire jquery and change the classes
b) duplicate only this part of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.canvas222').spinwheel({
       pplArray : ["sss", "aaa", "fff", "ggg","hhh", "jjj", "kkk", "lll","vvv", "bbb", "xxx", "eee"]
   });
});
```

this still don't show the results for the second wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue I saw with your code was that you didn't have the parameter set for the winner Element on your second instance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.canvas222').spinwheel({
       pplArray : ["sss", "aaa", "fff", "ggg","hhh", "jjj", "kkk", "lll","vvv", "bbb", "xxx", "eee"],
       winnerDiv:'.winner222' //Add "Winner" Element to the parameters
   });
});
```

jsFiddle of it working: https://jsfiddle.net/b7wjj39p/1/